# Making music CDs with ITunes

Tags: itunes, music, optical-drive, mp3, compatibility

I have 4 CDs I made from music tracks using iTunes and I was wondering if those are MP3 or some other format. Is it possible to read them with a non-MP3 player, such as a car CD player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a playable CD with iTunes, then the software converts them to a format that can be played through any hi-fi or CD player and burns that to a disc. If it was a data CD you used, then that works in a similar way to a USB flash drive, just copying the files and burning them to a CD. These will not be playable in a CD player, but you can get the files off from a computer. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I selected Audio Cd, is it readable then?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, and should play like any other CD in any CD players. Go ahead and try it out! Cheers.